# troubleshooting a random python twitter bot from github trying to get it to work

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

i'm attempting to run a twitter bot written in python that i found on github but i am getting errors.

this is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitterbot_retweet.py", line 15, in <module>
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=QUERY).items():
AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'search'
```

i have no idea what it means but the following is the code i am currently working with

```
import tweepy
from time import sleep
from credentials import *
from config import QUERY, FOLLOW, LIKE, SLEEP_TIME

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

print("Twitter bot which retweets,like tweets and follow users")
print("Bot Settings")
print("Like Tweets :", LIKE)
print("Follow users :", FOLLOW)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=QUERY).items():
    try:
        print('\nTweet by: @' + tweet.user.screen_name)

        tweet.retweet()
        print('Retweeted the tweet')

        # Favorite the tweet
        if LIKE:
            tweet.favorite()
            print('Favorited the tweet')

        # Follow the user who tweeted
        #check that bot is not already following the user
        if FOLLOW:
            if not tweet.user.following:
                tweet.user.follow()
                print('Followed the user')

        sleep(SLEEP_TIME)

    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print(e.reason)

    except StopIteration:
        break
```

thanks in advance. i've never worked on anything in python this technical before but i'm a quick learner.
this is where i got the code at... https://github.com/gauravssnl/Python-Twitter-Bot

(cont.)

so i changed

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=QUERY).items():
```

to

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q=QUERY).items():
```

and now this is the error i am receiving...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter-bot-0.py", line 20, in <module>
    tweet.retweet()
  File "/home/deusopus/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tweepy/models.py", line 369, in retweet
    return self._api.retweet(self.id)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'retweet'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter-bot-0.py", line 37, in <module>
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
AttributeError: module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'TweepError'
```

i have no idea what it means and the API documentation presents commands but as they are out of context, i struggle to grasp how they are implemented. like i said though, i am a quick learner and i appreciate any and all assistance. i'm just trying to have fun.

Comment: Word of advice - you're better off learning Python from tutorials, rather than copying someone else's code without understanding what is actually happening.

Comment: i was able to find some helpful people on the python discord server. the code i started with was wrong in a lot of places.

Answer (score 1):

`search` is not a valid attribute in tweepy. The correct attribute is `search_tweets`:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, q=QUERY).items():
```

[Reference](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=search_tweets#tweepy.API.search_tweets)

Comment: thank you for your help. i can't upvote your reply because i don't have enough karma points or whatever or else i would.